# Collection of Textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I am currently working on coding a 7 segment clock in Visual Basic for fun. It simply uses a bunch of textboxes as segments which turn either red or black depending on the number they're supposed to display.
the current code is very redumdant and looks basically like this for every group of segments:

```
        time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss")


    If CInt(Val(time.Substring(0, 1))) = 0 Then

        seg11.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg12.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg13.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg14.BackColor = Color.Black
        seg15.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg16.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg17.BackColor = Color.Red

    ElseIf CInt(Val(time.Substring(0, 1))) = 1 Then

        seg11.BackColor = Color.Black
        seg12.BackColor = Color.Black
        seg13.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg14.BackColor = Color.Black
        seg15.BackColor = Color.Black
        seg16.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg17.BackColor = Color.Black

    ElseIf time.Substring(0, 1) = 2 Then

        seg11.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg12.BackColor = Color.Black
        seg13.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg14.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg15.BackColor = Color.Red
        seg16.BackColor = Color.Black
        seg17.BackColor = Color.Red

    End If
```

My current plan is to create collections for the textboxes where I can predefine the functions so that the code isn't as redumdant as it is right now since I'm currently sitting on almost 500 lines of code for that simple thing

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this in designer and can't do that. In apple programming (objective-c) they will at least ask me if I want to create a control array.

That being said, while I hope there is a better answer, I think you can do something like

```
dim segcollection={seg11,seg12,seg13,seg14}
```

You can do this like once in the beginning of the program. After that you can simply do

```
for each seg in segcollection
    if j=l then
        seg.backcolor=red
    else
        seg.backcolor=blue
    end if        
next
```